# Unchecked warnings of java compiler does not occur in some cases

Tags: java, generics, javac

Consider this very simple generic class:

```
class GenericTest<T> {
    T t;
    GenericTest(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

I created multiple objects of this class, one of them is **raw type**:

```
class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest<String> test1 = new GenericTest<>("Test 1");
        GenericTest<String> test2 = new GenericTest<>("Test 2");
        GenericTest<String> test3 = new GenericTest<>("Test 3");

        GenericTest raw = new GenericTest(1.0); // Line 19

        test1 = raw; // Line 21
        test2 = raw; // Line 22
        raw = test3; // Line 23
    }
}
```

when compiling the project it shows **3 warnings** for these lines:

> ```
> App.java:19: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to GenericTest(T) as a member of the raw type GenericTest
> App.java:21: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
> App.java:22: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
> ```

**My question is why it doesn't give a warning for the third assignment `raw = test3;`?**

---

***One possible answer**: because it does not cause any further loss of type safety that already had occurred.*

- but it also was true when the second assignment `test2 = raw;` (line 22) so it should not issued any warning for the same reason, because it does not cause any further loss of type safety than line 21.

Comment: Java is statically typed, the type of `raw` doesn't change because of an assigment. So it still is `GenericTest` and not `GenericTest<String>`.

Comment: `raw` can hold all of them. `test1` and `test2` should crash after assigning them. There is no warning because no implicit unchecked casting happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consult the language specification for the definition of [Unchecked conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9):

> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw class or interface type (§4.8) G to any parameterized type of the form G<T1,...,Tn>.
>
> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw array type G[]k to any array type of the form G<T1,...,Tn>[]k. (The notation []k indicates an array type of k dimensions.)

Note that the direction of conversion is *from* raw *to* parameterized.

To answer the question as to why you don't need to be warned about a conversion in the parameterized to raw direction: yes, it's because "it does not cause any further loss of type safety that already had occurred", as you suggested in the question.